# ARCore and how do i remove it?

Tags: android

Please dont yell at me for asking this but how do I remove ARcore from my Android version 10? The apps page even tells me in red that it isnt compatible with my phone and to contact the developer. I did that and the no-reply email sent to me, stated to post my question here. If I cant remove it, will it be taking up space on my device or anything??

Comment: Just Uninstall from settings

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pc (or access to a pc), you can remove it using Usb Debugging on your android smartphone.

First, install android ADB tools in your pc from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)

Now, go to your smartphone settings, find build number, tap on build number 7-10 times in quick succession.

Then, you should find Developer Options in your Phone settings.
Open developer settings, find usb debugging, turn it on.

Now connect your phone to that pc using Usb cable and select file transfer mode.

Then , open command prompt, go to the adb  folder , then write this-

```
adb devices
```

If it detects your device, you're on the right track.If your phone shows any permission dialogue regarding usb debugging, grant it.
Then just paste-

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.ar.core
```

If it shows success, ARCore should be removed!

Comment: It Worked!!!  Even when im in developer mode in my phone, I still have apps that I cannot control or even click on. That was one of em! Its gone now though! ☺️